# Plotting pie chart using google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

This is my HTML code :

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['Table']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/getData.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  var myArr = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(myArr);
    data.addRows(myArr.length);
    data.addColumn('string','emp_name');
    data.addColumn('string','works_on');
    data.addColumn('datetime','time_from');
    data.addColumn('datetime','time_to');
    data.addColumn('number','Number of Hours');

  $.each(myArr, function(i,d) {
    data.setValue(i,0,d.emp_name);
    data.setValue(i,1,d.works_on);
    data.setValue(i,2,new Date(d.time_from));
    data.setValue(i,3,new Date(d.time_to));
  });

var formatter3 = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: "d-MM-yyyyTHH:mm:SS"});
formatter3.format(data,2);
formatter3.format(data,3);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data,null);

}
```

I want to plot a pie chart by calculating total working hour of each employee (ex : "ABC-10hr , xyz-5hr" etc) .Till now i have done this much of work and  Please help me in plotting part.

Comment: And my PHP code is :                                                                             `<?php 

$string = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8080/data.json");
echo $string;

?>`

Comment: And my data file is : `[
        { "emp_name": "ABC", "works_on": "wheels", "time_from": "2012-03-27 10:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-27 12:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "xyz", "works_on": "seat", "time_from": "2012-03-27 14:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-27 17:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "ABC", "works_on": "painting", "time_from": "2012-03-28 10:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-28 12:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "xyz", "works_on": "tube", "time_from": "2012-03-28 14:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-28 17:00:00" },

 ]`

Comment: Please help me in plotting part